# A few word puzzles 1

Tags: word, no-computers

Here are some short word puzzles.

1. What's a not uncommon 7 letter word containing all 5 vowels and "s" and one  other consonant (not necessarily in order)?
2. What's a common one syllable word, that when you add 1 letter to,  becomes three syllables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First answer

> SEQUOIA - redwood tree

and another answer for 2

> ORE -> OREO, thanks to the other answers for inspiration.

Comment: Ah I got stuck thinking on ious type words

Comment: Yes. That was an easy one.

Answer (score 15):

You did not ask for english words only, didn't you?  So for the first:

> oiseaux (birds in French)

The second could be seen on your face:

> [smile](http://www.syllablecount.com/syllables/smile) and [simile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simile)

or not....

Comment: I wish I could upvote again for your first answer.  Well done!

Comment: 2. No. Smile is 2 syllables, or am I weird? Smi-le

Comment: "Smile" is generally considered to be one syllable.

Comment: @ev3commander that's why I put a link to a page saying smile is considered one-syllable.

Comment: The problem is, in French, "Y" is also a vowel. Therefore, your first answer doesn't use all the vowels. Since the OP asked for the **5 vowels**, it's safe to say that French language, at least, is excluded.

Comment: @ MorganFR Y is in French, AFAIK, both a vowel and a [semiconsonant or semivowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel). So one can  interpret "all 5 vowels" as "all pure 5 vowels".

Answer (score 12):

Looks like someone already got to number one, but the answer to number two could be

> are +a = area

Comment: Correct. However, gtwebb gets the accept because his second answer is also acceptable, and he got first one right

Answer (score 9):

Another possible solution to (2):

> Rode / Rodeo

Sure there are many possible solutions in a similar vein.

Answer (score 7):

## 2

> came -> came**o** (English word)